# Spread out selected columns in a table

Tags: tables, tabularx, multirow

I am having troubles (again) with a table in `tabularx` where I would like to have fixed width for columns 2 to 5 and a table which is wide as the text block.

I also have a problem with the text in the first cell (`multirow`), which is not vertically centered.

The code I have so far is:

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{5pt}
\usepackage{caption} 
\captionsetup[table]{skip=5pt}
\newcolumntype{x}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{\label{Table}Indices}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l c c @{\extracolsep{8pt}} c c}
\toprule
\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{\textit{Index}}}    &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{\textit{Method 1}}}  &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{\textit{Method 2}}}  \\
\cmidrule{2-3}\cmidrule{4-5}
    & {\textbf{\textit{AA}}} & \textbf{\textit{BB}} & {\textbf{\textit{AA}}} & \textbf{\textit{BB}} \\
\midrule
A1      & 0.12\%    & 0.12\%    & 0.12\%    & 0.12\%    \\ \medskip\smallskip
A2      & 0.19\%    & 0.19\%    & 0.21\%    & 0.21\%    \\
B1  & 0.06\%    & 0.06\%    & 0.06\%    & 0.06\%    \\
B2  & 0.14\%    & 0.14\%    & 0.14\%    & 0.14\%    \\ \medskip\smallskip
B3          & 98.51\%   & 98.53\%   & 98.51\%   & 98.46\%   \\
C1  & 0.84\%    & 0.83\%    & 0.85\%    & 0.84\%    \\
C2  & 0.70\%    & 0.70\%    & 0.71\%    & 0.71\%    \\
C3  & 0.66\%    & 0.66\%    & 0.67\%    & 0.67\%    \\
C4  & 0.61\%    & 0.61\%    & 0.62\%    & 0.61\%    \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Obtaining the following results:

[image]

I tried also using simple `\tabular` environment, but I have problems with the `@{\extracolsep{8pt}}` and I do not think it is the most correct way to handle this problem.

Please note this is a table in a big document, which is separated in chapters and many packages are used for different needs. The style of the table should also remain the same to be consistent with the rest of the document.

Thanks a lot!

**EDIT**

I think I am getting closer using tabular environment:

```
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{\label{Table}Indices}
\begin{tabular}{m{3.50cm} x{2.3cm} x{2.3cm} @{\extracolsep{8pt}} x{2.3cm} x{2.3cm}}
\toprule
\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{\textit{Index}}}    &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{\textit{Method 1}}}  &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{\textit{Method 2}}}  \\
\cmidrule{2-3}\cmidrule{4-5}
    & {\textbf{\textit{AA}}} & \textbf{\textit{BB}} & {\textbf{\textit{AA}}} & \textbf{\textit{BB}} \\
\midrule
A1sometext here     & 0.12\%    & 0.12\%    & 0.12\%    & 0.12\%    \\ 
A2      & 0.19\%    & 0.19\%    & 0.21\%    & 0.21\%    \\  \medskip\smallskip
B1  & 0.06\%    & 0.06\%    & 0.06\%    & 0.06\%    \\
B2  & 0.14\%    & 0.14\%    & 0.14\%    & 0.14\%    \\ 
B3          & 98.51\%   & 98.53\%   & 98.51\%   & 98.46\%   \\  \medskip\smallskip
C1  & 0.84\%    & 0.83\%    & 0.85\%    & 0.84\%    \\
C2  & 0.70\%    & 0.70\%    & 0.71\%    & 0.71\%    \\
C3  & 0.66\%    & 0.66\%    & 0.67\%    & 0.67\%    \\
C4  & 0.61\%    & 0.61\%    & 0.62\%    & 0.61\%    \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Still I have the problem with the vertical centering of the first cell and the space between the rows (A2 to B1 and B3 to C1).

Comment: Please merge your code and put it into one compilable code fragment.

Comment: `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l c c @{\extracolsep{8pt}} c c}` tabularx can not work at all unless there is an `X` column but do not use `tabularx` for this type of table there is no line-breaking, so just use a normal tabular.

Comment: @TeXnician: done

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I tried going directly within tabular environment, and indeed it looks better, but I still have a couple of problems (see my edit). Thanks!

Comment: @Enrico 'Done' ?  neither of your examples has a `document` element it just makes it hard for people to help if you make examples that do not work,

Comment: @DavidCarlisle sorry, I am rather a noob. I have added the code. Hopefully it will be working now. Please let me know if there is something else I should do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are loading `siunitx` but not using it to align the table columns which makes the `98.xx` entries look out of line.

I show first with `tabular`, if you really want to distort the table to full width use `tabular*` but the main effect of that is to make the table harder to read.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{5pt}
\usepackage{caption} 
\captionsetup[table]{skip=5pt}


\begin{document}
\begin{table}\centering
\caption{\label{Table}Indices}
\begin{tabular}{l S S !{\hspace{2em}} S S}
\toprule
\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{\textit{Index}}}    &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{\textit{Method 1}}}  &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{\textit{Method 2}}}  \\
\cmidrule{2-3}\cmidrule{4-5}
    &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{\textit{AA}}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{\textit{BB}}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{\textit{AA}}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{\textit{BB}}} \\
\midrule
A1      & 0.12\%    & 0.12\%    & 0.12\%    & 0.12\%    \\ \medskip\smallskip
A2      & 0.19\%    & 0.19\%    & 0.21\%    & 0.21\%    \\
B1  & 0.06\%    & 0.06\%    & 0.06\%    & 0.06\%    \\
B2  & 0.14\%    & 0.14\%    & 0.14\%    & 0.14\%    \\ \medskip\smallskip
B3          & 98.51\%   & 98.53\%   & 98.51\%   & 98.46\%   \\
C1  & 0.84\%    & 0.83\%    & 0.85\%    & 0.84\%    \\
C2  & 0.70\%    & 0.70\%    & 0.71\%    & 0.71\%    \\
C3  & 0.66\%    & 0.66\%    & 0.67\%    & 0.67\%    \\
C4  & 0.61\%    & 0.61\%    & 0.62\%    & 0.61\%    \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}\centering
\caption{\label{Table2}Indices}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
l S S !{\hspace{2em}} S S
@{}}
\toprule
\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{\textit{Index}}}    &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{\textit{Method 1}}}  &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{\textit{Method 2}}}  \\
\cmidrule{2-3}\cmidrule{4-5}
    &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{\textit{AA}}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{\textit{BB}}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{\textit{AA}}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{\textit{BB}}} \\
\midrule
A1      & 0.12\%    & 0.12\%    & 0.12\%    & 0.12\%    \\ \medskip\smallskip
A2      & 0.19\%    & 0.19\%    & 0.21\%    & 0.21\%    \\
B1  & 0.06\%    & 0.06\%    & 0.06\%    & 0.06\%    \\
B2  & 0.14\%    & 0.14\%    & 0.14\%    & 0.14\%    \\ \medskip\smallskip
B3          & 98.51\%   & 98.53\%   & 98.51\%   & 98.46\%   \\
C1  & 0.84\%    & 0.83\%    & 0.85\%    & 0.84\%    \\
C2  & 0.70\%    & 0.70\%    & 0.71\%    & 0.71\%    \\
C3  & 0.66\%    & 0.66\%    & 0.67\%    & 0.67\%    \\
C4  & 0.61\%    & 0.61\%    & 0.62\%    & 0.61\%    \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}


\end{document}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful! Just one thing: is there a way to vertically center the first cell ("Index")?

Comment: @Enrico you can always use `\raisebox` to lower it (actually I'd just do that and not use `\multirow` at all) or you can look at the multirow package which offers some options to adjust the position.

Comment: Thanks, that worked out well by using `{\raisebox{-0.1cm}{\textbf{\textit{Index}}}}`. Last thing: the `cmidrule` in the first example does not break between the third and the fourth columns, while it does in the second example. Is there  simple solution? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Since no line-breaking should go on in columns 2 thru 5, using the `tabularx` machinery seems like overkill. I suggest you use a `tabular*` environment instead, along with the basic `r` column type for columns 2 thru 5. Observe the use of the `\addlinespace` macro (provided by the `booktabs` package) to insert a bit more vertical whitespace.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\usepackage{caption} 
\captionsetup[table]{skip=5pt}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} % make LaTeX figure out intercolumn whitespace
\caption{\label{Table}Indices}

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{p{3cm} @{\extracolsep{\fill}} rrrr}
\toprule
\textbf{\textit{Index}}  &   
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{\textit{Method 1}}}  &   
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{\textit{Method 2}}}  \\
\cmidrule{2-3} \cmidrule{4-5}
& \mc{\textbf{\textit{AA}}} & \mc{\textbf{\textit{BB}}} 
& \mc{\textbf{\textit{AA}}} & \mc{\textbf{\textit{BB}}} \\
\midrule
A1 some text here& 0.12\%  & 0.12\%  & 0.12\%  & 0.12\% \\ 
A2               & 0.19\%  & 0.19\%  & 0.21\%  & 0.21\% \\ 
\addlinespace
B1               & 0.06\%  & 0.06\%  & 0.06\%  & 0.06\% \\
B2               & 0.14\%  & 0.14\%  & 0.14\%  & 0.14\% \\ 
B3               & 98.51\% & 98.53\% & 98.51\% & 98.46\%\\ 
\addlinespace
C1               & 0.84\%  & 0.83\%  & 0.85\%  & 0.84\% \\
C2               & 0.70\%  & 0.70\%  & 0.71\%  & 0.71\% \\
C3               & 0.66\%  & 0.66\%  & 0.67\%  & 0.67\% \\
C4               & 0.61\%  & 0.61\%  & 0.62\%  & 0.61\% \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Observe that I've placed the word "Index" in the very first row of the table. This position highlights the facts that it (a) pertains to the first column and (b) is every bit as "important" as the headers over columns 2 thru 5.

Comment: Thanks @Mico, I see the results are very similar to the first answer, so I will keep using that code. But I will definitely add the `\addlinespace`, it is very useful, didn't know it.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution, with `tabularx` for determine equal with of columns with numbers and table width, `booktabs` for horizontal rules and additional space between some rows, and defined two new commands for simpler table typing. Vertical centering is obtained by `multirow` option.

[image]

For table width I select `0.75\textwidth`, but it is simple to change to desired  width. Note, that in table is used TeX primitive `cr` instead usually used `\\` or `tablenewline`. Reason is explained in [Joseph Wright answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/358085/positioning-of-append-to-numbers-in-the-last-s-column) to my question.

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{booktabs, multirow ,tabularx}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{skip=5pt}

\newcommand\mcxbf[1]{\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}{\bfseries\itshape #1}}
\newcommand\mccbf[1]{\multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries\itshape #1}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Indices}
\label{Table2}
\begin{tabularx}{0.75\textwidth}{c
                            *{4}{S[table-format=2.2,
                                   table-space-text-post=\,\%]<{\,\%}}                           
                                 }
    \toprule
\multirow{2}{*}[-0.25ex]{\textbf{\textit{Index}}}
    &   \mccbf{Method 1}            &   \mccbf{Method 2}            \cr
    \cmidrule(lr){2-3}\cmidrule(lr){4-5}
    &   \mcxbf{AA}  &   \mcxbf{BB}  &   \mcxbf{AA}  &   \mcxbf{BB}  \cr
    \midrule
A1  &   0.12        &   0.12        &   0.12        &   0.12        \cr
A2  &   0.19        &   0.19        &   0.21        &   0.21        \cr  
    \addlinespace
B1  &   0.06        &   0.06        &   0.06        &   0.06        \cr
B2  &   0.14        &   0.14        &   0.14        &   0.14        \cr
B3  &   98.51       &   98.53       &   98.51       &  98.46        \cr  
    \addlinespace
C1  &   0.84        &   0.83        &   0.85        &   0.84        \cr
C2  &   0.70        &   0.70        &   0.71        &   0.71        \cr
C3  &   0.66        &   0.66        &   0.67        &   0.67        \cr
C4  &   0.61        &   0.61        &   0.62        &   0.61        \cr
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```