# Positioning of \% append to numbers in the last S column

Tags: tables, siunitx

Please, consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\newcommand\mcp[1]{\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{22mm}}{\bfseries#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c
           *{4}{S[table-format=2.2,
                  table-space-text-post=\,\%]<{\,\%}}
                }
    \hline
    &   \mcp{AA}    &   \mcp{BB}    &   \mcp{AA}    &   \mcp{BB}    \\
    \hline
A1  &   0.12        &   0.12        &   0.12        &   0.12        \\
A2  &   0.19        &   0.19        &   0.21        &   0.21        \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

which gives the following result:

[image]

Why the last column is not formatted on the some way as other `S` columns before it? Do I miss something in options of `S` columns?

Comment: don't use `p` columns for numerical data

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I use `p{...}` (or `X`) column type for formatting column headers, which haven't numbers. With this I can define equal columns width or multi line headers without manual breaking of text in them.

Comment: headers normally (as here) require a multicolumn{1} anyway so do not use the same column specification as the data cells.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `\bfseries #1` rather than `\textbf #1`?

Comment: of course, in my experiments and testing I now already use `\bfserie`, but in the beginning I use `\textbf{#1}` ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a documented situation ([`siunitx`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/siunitx) manual, section 7.13): use the low-level `\cr` here:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\newcommand\mcp[1]{\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{22mm}}{\bfseries #1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}%{\linewidth}{
         {   c
       *{4}{S[table-format=2.2,
              table-space-text-post=\,\%]<{\,\%}}
                            }
    \hline
    &   \mcp{AA}    &   \mcp{BB}    &   \mcp{AA}    &   \mcp{BB}    \cr
    \hline
A1  &   0.12        &   0.12        &   0.12        &   0.12        \cr
A2  &   0.19        &   0.19        &   0.21        &   0.21        \cr
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: hmmm define a `\crbackslash` instead of `\arraybackslash`?  `\arraybackslash` is carefully setting `\\ ` to the tabular version which then doesn't work anyway:-)

Comment: Thank you very much! This works. Please, be so kind and mention in your answer, where this situation is documented.

Comment: I have found that adding a dummy `c@{}` column at the end, with trailing `&` has the same effect and allows using ``\\`` (with its features for adding space).

Answer (score 4):

You can use a dummy column. I present two implementations of your table, the second one with `tabular*`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{siunitx}

% use this if the headers are just one line long
%\newcommand\mcp[1]{%
%  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\makebox[22mm]{\bfseries #1}}%
%}
\newcommand\mcp[1]{%
  \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}p{22mm}}{\bfseries #1}%
}

% for the second table
\newcommand{\tbh}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries #1}}

\begin{document}

\centering

\begin{tabular}{
  c
  *{4}{S[table-format=2.2,table-space-text-post=\,\%]<{\,\%}}
  c@{}
}
\hline
    & \mcp{AA} & \mcp{BB} & \mcp{AA} & \mcp{BB} & \tabularnewline
\hline
A1  &   0.12   &   0.12   &   0.12   &   0.12   & \\[2ex]
A2  &   0.19   &   0.19   &   0.21   &   0.21   & \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
  @{\hspace{\tabcolsep}\extracolsep{\fill}}
  c
  *{4}{S[table-format=2.2,table-space-text-post=\,\%]<{\,\%}}
  @{\extracolsep{0pt}}c@{\hspace{\tabcolsep}}
}
\hline
    & \tbh{AA} & \tbh{BB} & \tbh{AA} & \tbh{BB} & \\
\hline
A1  &   0.12   &   0.12   &   0.12   &   0.12   & \\[2ex]
A2  &   0.19   &   0.19   &   0.21   &   0.21   & \\
\hline
\end{tabular*}

\end{document}
```

[image]